# $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] extract mail client

Tags: php, tracking, user-agent, html-email

Currently I'm trying to create a mailing system with statistics. I send a mail with an image which links to a file where I can read the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. When I open the mail in thunderbird this is my user-agent:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130328 Thunderbird/17.0.5`
I'd like to get the name and the version of the mailclient.

I tried to use 
`stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'thunderbird')` but there are alot of email clients and if I make an if else structure with all of the clients it will get very big and I will always miss some email clients. how can I extract it the easy way and get a result like [THIS](http://user-agent-string.info/?Fuas=Mozilla/5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.2;%20WOW64;%20rv:17.0%29%20Gecko/20130328%20Thunderbird/17.0.5&test=837&action=analyze)?

Comment: So use their PHP version: http://user-agent-string.info/download/UASparser-for-PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://php.net/get_browser. Note that it requires a 3rd party text file that holds information regarding browsers/clients which can be parsed by get_browser()

You can obtain the latest php_browscap.ini at http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/

Edit: I checked to be sure, but the files contains Thunderbird too.

Comment: This will only get the browser and the third party text file has to be updated when there is a change...

Comment: You don't have to update the file that often and you can write a script or cronjob to automatically do that for you. Thunderbird has a browser too, I think it should work fine. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: haven't tried it simply because it is a lot of work:) different clients have also different versions so list will take some time to make.

Comment: You just have to download the zip, extract the php ini file and put it in the right location. 
http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/ "In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on your system"

Takes about 2 minutes ;)

Comment: the latest (final) version of thunderbird is 17.0.5 this one is not included in the file? the rest of the email clients are included as far as I know. I think i will use this:)